# Solutions for pagination with search functionality

Tags: codeigniter

I have a page with search functionality. 
In order to continue the search parameters when pagination is required, I have to pass the search term to the pagination links.

```
$config['reuse_query_string'] = FALSE;

By default your Query String arguments (nothing to do with other query string options) will be ignored. Setting this config to TRUE will add existing query string arguments back into the URL after the URI segment and before the suffix.:

http://example.com/index.php/test/page/20?query=search%term

This helps you mix together normal URI Segments as well as query string arguments, which until 3.0 was not possible.
```

But setting this to TRUE does not automatically add the search query after the URI offset segment (after a search is performed). 
However, I did manage to use

```
$config['suffix'] = "?my_search_input=$my_query_value";
```

to create pagination links that look something like `/method/controller/20/?my_search_input=hello`

But my question is...

Is this the best way to do it, and why didn't `$config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;` append this back to the URL automatically? 
Am I not understanding the documentation correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Your pagination links need to contain the GET string, nothing is ever automatic... to do this you need to generate them in the href

Comment: So is `$config['suffix']` the correct place to put the query and get string? 

I think I understand now about `reuse_query_string`. It looks like setting it to TRUE, will pass the query string to the first pagination link after you have navigated to another pagination link. Mentioned here: http://blog.marcomonteiro.net/post/codeigniter-pagination-re-use-query-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this change code with your requirment and your table

set controller this way

```
    <?php
class pagination extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->model('pagination_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //pagination settings
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('pagination/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tbl_books');
        $config['per_page'] = "3";
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

        // integrate bootstrap pagination
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '«';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '»';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        // get books list
        $data['booklist'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books($config["per_page"], $data['page'], NULL);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        // load view
        $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);
    }

    function search()
    {
        // get search string
        $search = ($this->input->post("book_name"))? $this->input->post("book_name") : "NIL";

        $search = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : $search;

        // pagination settings
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = site_url("pagination/search/$search");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books_count($search);
        $config['per_page'] = "5";
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

        // integrate bootstrap pagination
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        // get books list
        $data['booklist'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books($config['per_page'], $data['page'], $search);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        //Load view
        $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

set model this way

```
    <?php
class pagination_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //fetch books
    function get_books($limit, $start, $st = NULL)
    {
        if ($st == "NIL") $st = "";
        $sql = "select * from tbl_books where name like '%$st%' limit " . $start . ", " . $limit;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_books_count($st = NULL)
    {
        if ($st == "NIL") $st = "";
        $sql = "select * from tbl_books where name like '%$st%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}
?>
```

view look like this

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CodeIgniter Pagination Example with Search Query Filter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">

    <style type="text/css">
    .bg-border {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 4px 4px;
        padding: 15px 15px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 well">
        <?php 
        $attr = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "role" => "form", "id" => "form1", "name" => "form1");
        echo form_open("pagination/search", $attr);?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" id="book_name" name="book_name" placeholder="Search for Book Name..." type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('book_name'); ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="btn_search" name="btn_search" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Search" />
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(). "index.php/pagination/index"; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Show All</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bg-border">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Book Name</th>
                    <th>Author Name</th>
                    <th>ISBN</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($booklist); ++$i) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo ($page+$i+1); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $booklist[$i]->name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $booklist[$i]->author; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $booklist[$i]->isbn; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <?php echo $pagination; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just going through it. I have one question though. The parts that say `"NIL"`, do you mean `NULL`?

Comment: yeah thats null@user3442612

Comment: Thanks, I decided to come up with my own solution, but I appreciate the code. I'll mark it as the accepted answer as it looks like a viable solution.